# reference path of make

Tags: linux, makefile

I've just started learning about 'make' commands and other stuffs that derive from it.
I got this good reference html page that taught me about 'make' concepts
http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/howto_makefiles.html
and it says, somethings like this

quote:

```
*# define any directories containing header files other than /usr/include
#
INCLUDES = -I/home/newhall/include  -I../include
# define library paths in addition to /usr/lib
#   if I wanted to include libraries not in /usr/lib I'd specify
#   their path using -Lpath, something like:
LFLAGS = -L/home/newhall/lib  -L../lib
# define any libraries to link into executable:
#   if I want to link in libraries (libx.so or libx.a) I use the -llibname 
#   option, something like (this will link in libmylib.so and libm.so:
LIBS = -lmylib -lm*
```

Well here's the thing I don't understand. I don't get why you have to include

seperate header files with INCLUDES and LFLAGS. what's the difference of files that are in /usr/lib and /usr/include ? It seems pretty much the same
to me since both includes a path of header files that aren't shared objects(+archieves) or in the environmental path.

plus, since, usr/include is a default path when compiling, does all the files that are in the sub-directory included as well?? for example, what i'm trying to do is, I want to include /usr/include/gtk+-3.0 as an additional path but since it's a sub directory, will I have to include it?

Answer (score 2):

Actually this doesn't include any headers or libraries, the `-I` option tells the compiler where to find headers (other than the standard ones) included in the source code with `#include` and `-L` tells the linker where to find libraries linked with `-l` option.

In other words, they add directories to the search path, not actual headers or libraries...

Variable names are completely arbitrary, they do however indicate which options belong to which tool, example LFLAGS (linker flags) CFLAGS (compiler flags).

`/usr/lib` and `/usr/include` usually contain the system libraries and headers respectively.

I suggest you read more about C and GCC before moving to make, as it's just used to script the compilation process.

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/lib` contains libraries of object files that get linked to the executable. `/usr/include` contains header files that contain declarations of functions, types and structures used with the libraries. They are two separate things.

Answer (score 0):

1. INCLUDES specifies path where compiler will search for .c and .h files you include in your program. i.e. If you write to include test.h in your program compiler will search in same directory of your C file as well as directories you specified using INCLUDES in make file.
2. LFLAGS specifies library paths. Which contains libraries you use for your program. The reason behind differentiating it with INCLUDES is that INCLUDES contains source files where as LFLAGS contanis only binary files. And also for distributing any C utility its standard 
   convention to used two different folder for source and libs.
3. To use files resided in /usr/include/gtk+-3.0 you can include it as #include "gtk+-3.0/filename.h". As /usr/include is included in your INCLUDES you can give relative path from that directory.